# Invalid login attempt in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am currently changing the default template of MVC5 project (with identity). When I first time register and login, all goes well. But when I made some changes like project at default level stores UserName as Email. But when I make change it to store UserName as from Form then it gives 'Invalid' login attempt. Can anyone tell me that where I am going wrong. Either I have to make changes at any other places if yes then where?

Here are my register function:

Before:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

I have changed this line to this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.usrName, Email = model.Email , PhoneNumber=model.Contact};
```

And my login function is as it comes in default. like,

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Now, can someone please tell me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change UserName from `model.Email` to `model.usrName`, you have to use `model.usrName` in your Login function. Like this:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.usrName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Because `UserName` and `Password` fields are default unique parameters to login. So it wants to complete login operation with UserName field.

Comment: No, i want to login from email. but after adding userName in signup. it does not logging in from email.